# Ubuntu install with pxe boot (UEFI)

Tags: ubuntu, pxe-boot, uefi

Do I need to create a special configuration to install an ubuntu server with uefi over network pxe boot? I have on my boot server the default pxelinux.0 file. After installation of a new hardware i have checked the filesystem [`/sys/firmware/efi/vars/`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148356/how-to-know-if-im-booting-using-uefi) and the uefi folder has files. With this my system should run under uefi.

Since I have found some instructions in the internet on how to set up a uefi pxe boot server, I am now not quite clear whether this is really needed since it seems to work without it. [Ubuntu – Setup PXE Server using pxelinux files only Bios & UEFI Support](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13808)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NBP (you mention pxelinux.0 for pcbios) needs to be different for EFI, so the hardest part of getting it working for both pcbios and efi is to configure DHCP server correctly.

For EFI many use grub, there is also iPXE.
I found [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-arm64) which mentions all but the dhcp part.

In regards to DHCP [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robinsmidsrod/4008017) uses isc dhcpd, and has a focus on iPXE, but the idea can be applied to grub efi + legacy pxelinux combination as well.

Comment: Does this mean it is not possible to install a linux in uefi mode with (pxelinux.0 for pcbios)? But how can it be that my machine shows that it runs under uefi?

Comment: pxelinux.0 will most definitely be pcbios, (unless a efi file was taken and then renamed)
But it would be totally possible to run installation in pcbios mode, create disk partitions that is efi compatible (FAT32 partition with bootx64.efi, assuming x86_64)
BIOS/firmware could then boot from this disk, and everything would be EFI

Using pxelinux.0 you will probably not be using EFI, installing to disk and restart, could get you booted in EFI mode.

Comment: Okay if this is possible what advantage would I have if I also boot with UEFI in PXE mode?

Comment: EFI is generally faster (especially when disabling legacy support, CSM) and has less limitations, If PXE is something you do often, then having both simplifies the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Serva PXE server; a single exe that does everything automatically.
[https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)